# Values Hidden From Source Code- Webscraping Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web-scrape a website and when I go through the source code, what I'm looking for is not there. Website is http://www.providentmetals.com/2016-1-oz-canadian-silver-cougar.html and what I'm looking for is the price in the table in the top-right. It says "1+" followed by prices. It's around $18.04 right now.
When I "inspect element" with web developer tools, I can see the price though.
Using BeautifulSoup I've tried to get the value, but it doesn't show up. Here's rougly the code.
It doesn't return a value at all

```
import res,bs4
url='http://www.providentmetals.com/2016-1-oz-canadian-silver.cougar.html'
res=requests.get(url)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
elems=soup.findAll('class',{'table':'table table-striped border-light pricing data-table'})
#table name found from inspect element web dev tool
```

Questions: How do I find the hidden data? Are there any ways that you know of to use bs4/requests to find the data? I'm not great at coding and webscraping, so any help would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are not hidden, they are obtained with an Ajax request and then inserted into the page's DOM. That's why you see them in your browser, but not in the page's HTML.

You can directly access the Ajax request that obtains the data you require. The response is in JSON format, so it's really easy to use. You need to know the SKU which, for your example, is BBFS-04253.

The URL is:
http://www.providentmetals.com/services/products.php?type=product&sku=BBFS-04253

Using the `requests` module:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.providentmetals.com/services/products.php'
params = {'type': 'product', 'sku': 'BBFS-04253'}
response = requests.get(url, params)
data = response.json()

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data)
[{u'as_low_as': {u'crypto_price': u'$18.22',
                 u'list_price': u'$18.78',
                 u'price': u'$18.03',
                 u'qty': 1,
                 u'to_tier': u' + '},
  u'crypto_price': u'$18.22',
  u'crypto_special_price': u'$0.00',
  u'id': u'6034',
  u'inStock': None,
  u'list_price': u'$18.78',
  u'list_special_price': u'$0.00',
  u'name': u'2016 1 oz Canadian Silver Cougar | Predator Series',
  u'price': u'$18.03',
  u'sell_to_us': u'$16.69',
  u'sku': u'BBFS-04253',
  u'special_price': None,
  u'status_allows_price': True,
  u'stock_status_code': u'pre-sale',
  u'tier_price': [{u'crypto_price': u'$18.22',
                   u'list_price': u'$18.78',
                   u'price': u'$18.03',
                   u'qty': 1,
                   u'to_tier': u' + '}]}]
    print data['price']
```

So you can access the price and other details directly:

```
>>> data[0]['price']
u'$18.03'
>>> data[0]['name']
u'2016 1 oz Canadian Silver Cougar | Predator Series'
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Just one question. Response=requests.get(url, params) gives me a TypeError saying that it only takes 1 argument. What should I do about this? I'm using Python 3

Comment: It shouldn't do that, something is wrong. The code that I've posted works fine in Python 2 and 3. You don't happen to have a module of your own named `requests.py` that contains a function named `get()`? What is the module `res` that you import in your question?

Comment: I got it now. I just had to change params to something else and do the following:
    response=requests.get(url, params=somethingElse)

Comment: Quick question so I know how to do this in the future. How did you know to search for providentmetals.com/services/products.php ?
How did you know to write exactly {'type': 'product', 'sku': 'BBFS-04253'} ? If a website didn't have json data available, how would you know? Thank you by the way :)

Comment: I used Firebug to view the HTTP requests when loading the page. There are similar extensions available or builtin to most browsers. Looking at those requests I noticed the one that retrieves the price information and found that it returns JSON data. From there it was just a matter of looking at the parameters sent in the HTTP request. Not all sites are as easy to analyze as this one.